# How can i change selection by pressing specific keyboard key in a html list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the selection of `li` by pressing the `p` keyboard key. In my example below I manage to change the selection and automatically change the color of the selection to yellow but I have a problem that it goes down to a specific point also when you scroll down it does not go to the next `li` that is in row.

I want to create something that after I press the `p` button on the keyboard to select the first element `li` and change the background to `yellow` to be noticed that we are currently on that `li` element, then after pressing it again to select the second `li` element and so on..

**Here is my current code**  [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-zsrqbf?file=index.js)

```js
var lis = document.getElementById('steps').getElementsByTagName('li');
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 80) {
    pos = window.scrollY;
    fnd = false;
    for (const li of lis) {
      li.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    }
    for (const li of lis) {
      if (fnd) {
        li.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        window.scrollTo(
          window.scrollX,
          pos + li.getBoundingClientRect().top - 100
        );
        break;
      }
      fnd = li.getBoundingClientRect().top > 100;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<ul id="steps">
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
    industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather make use of the `Sibling` property this will loop once you reach the end

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-xrmrgm?file=index.html)

```js
  var lis = document.getElementById('steps').getElementsByTagName('li');
  let isFirst = true;
  let currentElement = lis[0];
  document.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 80) {
      pos = window.scrollY;
      fnd = false;
      for (const li of lis) {
        li.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
      }
      if(isFirst){
        isFirst = false;
      } else {
        if (currentElement.nextElementSibling) {
          currentElement = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
        } else {
          currentElement = lis[0];
        }
      }
      currentElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';

      window.scrollTo({
        left: window.scrollX,
        top: pos + currentElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - 100,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  };
```